# $\int_{1}^{\infty} xf'(x) \space dx$ converges absolutely. Prove\disprove: $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(\xi) \space d\xi$ converges absolutely.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Let $f:[1, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f$ is differentiable at $[1, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0.$ 
> Suppose that $f'$ is Riemann-integrable and the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} xf'(x) \space dx$ converges absolutely.
>
>  **Prove\disprove:  $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(\xi) \space d\xi$ converges absolutely.**

Since I've observed & proved the discrete version of this argument, I suspect it is true at its "continues" version as well (which is much more applicable and therefore, in my opinion, more interesting).

 So far I couldn't find a counter-example as well as I struggle to think of a proof strategy for this.

I'd like to have a bit of guidance here, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this kinf of question, it is often useful to think $f$ as the integral of its derivative (since the information you have is on the derivative). The convergence toward $0$ of $f$, you have,
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{+\infty} |f(x)| \, dx & = \int_1^{+\infty} \left|\int_x^{+\infty} f'(t) \, dt\right| \, dx\\
& \leqslant \int_1^{+\infty} \int_1^t |f'(t)| \, dx \, dt \textrm{ by Fubini-Tonelli,}\\
& = \int_1^{+\infty} (t - 1)|f'(t)| \, dt\\
& < +\infty.
\end{align*}
It proves that $\displaystyle \int_1^{+\infty} f(x) \, dx$ converges (absolutely by the way), and you conclude with an integration by parts.

**Edit : other method without Fubini-Tonelli.** Notice that if $x \mapsto xf(x)$ converges at infinity toward some limit $l$, then $l \neq 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \sim \frac{l}{x} \Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_1^\infty f(x) \, dx = \mathrm{sign}(l)\infty$. Therefore, $l$ must equal $0$. Let us prove directly that $xf(x) \rightarrow 0$.

We have for all $x$, still using $f(x) \rightarrow 0$,
$$
|xf(x)| = x\left|\int_x^{+\infty} f'(t) \, dt\right| \leqslant \int_x^{+\infty} \frac{x}{t}|tf'(t)| \, dt \leqslant \int_x^{+\infty} |tf'(t)| \, dt \rightarrow 0,
$$
because $t \mapsto tf'(t)$ is integrable. Therefore, $xf(x) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Can you see a way to prove it without implicitly using Fubini-Tonelli theorem which I am unfamiliar with? Thanks!

Comment: I added an other method. By the way, the limit necessarily equals $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I've made some edits too in order to be more precise with your answer. 
By the way, the idea of the second proof is also applicable at the discrete form of that argument by using (analogously) summation by parts (it's pretty cool imo since it draws parallels between the two).